# Pass arrays data from a ViewController to a TableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

I couldn't find this specific case where i have to pass and append two or more arrays of string into a TableView located in 2nd ViewController.
I want to push two different strings inside two different UILabels

I have some data that gets inside through a UIAlertViewController in mainViewController

```
var name = alertController.textFields?[0].text
var number = alertController.textFields?[1].text
```

Then i take this data and every time i get new set of name/number i append it to arrays of string in MainVC

```
var playerNames = [String]()
var playerNumbers = [String]()
self.playerNames.append(name!)
self.playerNumbers.append(number!)
```

now i created a table view and a custom cell with .xib and i'd call it and set to custom labels like this

TableView in Second ViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {

customCell.tableViewCellNumber.text = mainVC.playerNumbers[indexPath.row]
customCell.tableViewCellName.text = mainVC.playerNames[indexPath.row]
return customCell
}
```

So for every new set it makes a new row with name + number
[image: customCell image]

I tried anything from userDefaults to performForSegue but it doesnt work!
I can print the arrays just fine, but it wont show me new rows at all.

**EDIT: actual question**

Ok I guess I misunderstood the use of NsUserDefaults... at the moment i have in viewDidLoad of my 2nd controller

```
if ((UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "playerNames")) != nil){
            let playerNames = (UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: 
"playerNames") as? [String])!
            print(playerNames)
        }

    }
```

and its actually printing the new values, now i want the new appended value to show in the custom cell label.text  `cell.nameLabel.text = The Value`  how do i retrieve the value everytime and store it? 
if i try with playerNames, it says it doesnt exist..

Comment: Tough to tell without seeing more code. Are you calling `tableView.reloadData()` when your data set is initialized or changes?

Comment: Hey, edited and added the whole VC, a lot of stuff is happening in that createView() so its not easy. I tried reloadData inside CellForRowAt Index Path, but it's not working. I guess it's just me, I have no idea how to make UserDefaults working, since if I try to print the array in ViewWillAppear of 2nd viewController, the actual arrays are there.

Comment: I would suggest calling `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear` of the 2nd view controller not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. `tableView.reloadData()` will redisplay the table view and trigger calls to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: i edited my question with the actual more accurate question.. can you please advise on this Chris?

Answer (score 0):

Did you synchronize user defaults after inputting data? UserDefaults.synchronize()

Comment: Do I have to synchronize it inside the cells? Should I do it inside CellForRowAt IndexPath?

Comment: This intends to be a comment other than answer.

Comment: I can't comment because I don't have a high enough reputation. I wish I could comment on other peoples posts. Sue Me

Comment: dan do it right after you insert something into userdefaults